# Replit Removes all data from selenium after restarts

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, replit

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors=yes')
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://discord.com/login")

try:
  WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[name='email']")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[name='password']")))
finally:
  email_input = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "email")
  email_input.send_keys(os.environ['email'])
  pass_input = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "password")
  pass_input.send_keys(os.environ['password'])
  time.sleep(1)
  pass_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

I have made a Discord logger. It login discord successfully. but after i restart the login informations are gone. it’s start again in loging page.

I am using Replit so i think it is problem with replit.

I also tried login using token but that doesn’t work. i have to use only email and password login for that now. i just want to fix that it will storing all login information even i restarts it remains.